# Fetching data from REDIS with NODE JS and BLUEBIRD

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, promise, bluebird

I am trying to fetching all entries for a particular key patterns and to make the callback happen neatly, I am using Bluebird. The redis client for nodejs is node_redis for the project.

The code in redis client is -

```
    exports.getAllRedisKeysA = function() {
  var res = rclient.keysAsync("client*").then(function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
  }).then(function(data) {
    var arrayResp = [];
    for (var element in data) {
      rclient.hgetallAsync(element).then(function(data) {
        arrayResp.push(data);
      });
    };
    return arrayResp;
    //  console.log(data);
  }).catch(console.log.bind(console));
  console.log(res); // gives an empty promise.
  return res;
}
```

And this function is being called from a controller in the manner below -

```
var abc = rdata.getAllRedisKeysA();
// console.log(abc); // gives undefined
```

The console.log output inside the redis function gives an empty promise and nothing is returned to the controller.

Am I missing anything in the implementation?

Comment: `arrayResp` will always be an empty array when you return it, because promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous  - also, at the point you are console logging res, it will be a pending promise, because promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous

Comment: what's the way to go about it? How can I resolve this?

Comment: First off, you [should use `SCAN` instead of `KEYS`](http://redis.io/commands/keys). Second, as @JaromandaX says, you cannot return the result of asynchronous operations. Third, you shouldn't use `for(... in ...)` for arrays. The way to go about it would be to return a promise when you have fetched all the keys. I'm not familiar with Bluebird but [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) seems, well, promising.

Comment: Thank you Linus, I am not quite sure but I'll try this approach. I have been successful a bit in fetching the keys, but failing in the arrays part. Will let you know.

Comment: where did you find any docs in the first place? i seem to e completely in the dark here trying to use sails-redis

Comment: @Paulo did the accepted answer not work for you? I haven't used sails+redis.

Comment: the accepted answer does work for the given case... but i can't find any docs if  want to explore further @swateek

Comment: for example, how do you execute an update, or an updateAll etc

Comment: so sorry, in our design we moved to pyredis. That was really helpful and has served us well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295262/linus-gustav-larsson-thiel) and [Jaromanda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) had some real helpful comments to the question that helped me move in the right direction. I have used the below way to fetch my required data from REDIS using BlueBird Promise and here's how this needs be done.

**The code below gets the required data from REDIS**

```
exports.getRedisKeyPattern = function(pattern){

var allKeys = allKeysPattern(pattern).then(function(data){
  var arrayResp = [];
  var inptArr = [];
  var newdata = data.slice(1)[0];
  for(var i in newdata){
    inptArr.push(newdata[i]);
  };
  return new Promise.resolve(inptArr);
});

var valuePerKey = Promise.mapSeries(allKeys, function(dt){
  return getAllKeyContents(dt);
}).then(function(res){
  return res;
}).catch(function(err) { console.log("Argh, broken: " + err.message);
});

return new Promise.resolve(valuePerKey);
}

function getAllKeyContents(key){
  var data =  rclient.hgetallAsync(key).then(function(data){
      return data;
  }).catch(function(err) { console.log("Argh, broken: " + err.message); });

  var res = Promise.join(data, key, function(data, key){
      return {
          key: key,
          data: data
      };
    });

  return res;
}
```

From the controller, the function is called like this -

```
var rdata = require('../../components/redis/redis-functions');
rdata.getRedisKeyPattern("clients*").then(function(response){
      return res.status(200).json(response);
    });
```

The .js file which contains the redis functions is included into the controller file so that functions can be used.